# Best way to bake a breakfast casserole and reheat a ham in the same oven

Tags: baking, ham, casserole

I’d like to bake my breakfast casserole & reheat ham chunks at the same time in the same oven. I fear the breakfast casserole may taste like ham. If I cover the ham will that help?

Answer (score 2):

Covering your ham (with a lid or foil) will not only mitigate the mingling of aromas, but will also allow you to reheat the ham in a shorter amount of time.  You could add a small amount (1/4 - 1/2 cup) of boiling water to the pan with the ham to generate some steam.